# Quote add format to GrandTotal value

Tags: formula, email-template, configuration, quote

I have issue with formatting this field.
I want to display it formatted in email template subject, therefore I cannot use the regular usage in visualforce like:

```
<apex:outputText value="{0, number, ###,###,###,##0.00}">
    <apex:param value="{!Quote.GrandTotal}" />
</apex:outputText>
```

I tried as alternative solution to create formula field in Quote that will hold the formatted value, but when creating formula seems this field is not available.

Does anyone have other idea for implementing this or why I cannot use the GrandTotal field in formula?
The only idea I can see now is creating regular field and populate it with code...

Comment: This is not related to FLS

Comment: I have faced similar situation earlier, no formula fields are supported in Subject (not even Grand Total). For testing purpose, create a formula text and try to show the quote's name, it will not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Formula field doesn't support in Subject of Email template.

So better to create Currency field and update this currency field through the trigger.

And, finally use the currency field on the Subject of Email template.

Comment: I'll try further to find another solution, and if will run out of option I'll do this approach. Thanks.